# insertar (con insert()) un elemento al recorrer arreglo python

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo el sig. codigo. Lo que quiero es con la funcion insert() insertar un numero (especificamente el 0) al arreglo si una condicion (si el numero es negativo) se cumple, luego de dicho numero. Por ejemplo, en el arreglo tengo los n 1,-3,6 y quiero que me devuelva 1,-3,**0**,6
Pero me manda error con este codigo y me marca que es cuando intento insertar el elemento deseado. (Primero se me traba el programa y tarda en mandar el error)

Mi cod. es:

```
def insertar(a):
    for i in a:
        if i<0:
            a.insert(a[i],0)
```

Comment: No repitas preguntas. Esta ya fue cerrada.

Comment: la opcion que me da no contesta la pregunta.

Comment: O sea, querés la opción no recomendada (modificar la lista mientras la recorres)?

Comment: Mirando tu código, veo que estas tratando de usar la variable "i" tanto como item de la lista como indice. No creo que sea eso lo que buscas.

Comment: lo que quiero es un codigo (utilizando el metodo insert) que me funcione correctamente,quiza no se usar la rta recomendada para lo que busco.
Y sí, quiero modificar la lista original mientras la recorro, con eliminar (remove), funciona, con incert no tanto

Comment: No pidas un código, pide una respuesta. Recuerda que no somos un repositorio de código ni un servicio de código. Sobre lo que buscas, como te conté en mi respuesta, tendrás que hacer un contador que se vaya actualizando segun agregas items.

Comment: Buen punto @DanteS., el tema que la solución que obtuve con remove no se porque no la puedo aplicar al insert, se me ejecuta mal. Incluso intente con otra lista y agregarlos, me se agregan mal.
def insertar(a):
    lista_nueva = a.copy()
    for i in a:
        if i < 0:
            lista_nueva.insert(i, 0)
    return lista_nueva

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142462/discussion-between-dante-s-and-severus-lightwood).